# How to fix IOError in _load_libtiff function?

Tags: python, keras, python-imaging-library

I use flow_from_dataframe function in order to augment my dataset.

however when,

```
train= data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_df,
                                               directory=None,
                                               x_col='image_name',
                                               y_col='label',
                                               class_mode="raw",
                                               target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                               batch_size=2048)
for i in train:
    break
```

**I iterate over the output in order to save my images I found IOError.**

> for i in train:

```
  File "C:\Users\m.seifikar\PycharmProjects\firmfile\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 104, in __next__
    return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\m.seifikar\PycharmProjects\firmfile\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 116, in next
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "C:\Users\m.seifikar\PycharmProjects\firmfile\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 230, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    interpolation=self.interpolation)
  File "C:\Users\m.seifikar\PycharmProjects\firmfile\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 119, in load_img
    img = img.convert('RGB')
  File "C:\Users\m.seifikar\PycharmProjects\firmfile\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 912, in convert
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\m.seifikar\PycharmProjects\firmfile\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1077, in load
    return self._load_libtiff()
  File "C:\Users\m.seifikar\PycharmProjects\firmfile\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1168, in _load_libtiff
    raise IOError(err)
OSError: -9
```

Comment: Looks like you are using TIFF images but you don't have libtiff installed.

Comment: no, I have it @MatiasValdenegro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem. when we use flow_from_dataframe we should specify the color mode(the default is RGB). if our image is in grey mode and we use the default setting this error will be raised.